# CanExecute WPF command on field change

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, canexecute

What I want to do is fairly simple however I have not seen examples online with respect on how to do it. I want an 'Update' button to become enabled if a field has been changed.

Context: I have a WPF form which updates a row in a database. I do not want the user to be able to click the 'Update' button unless he/she has modified some form value. I am using the MVVM pattern and have 4 properties which can be updated (Name, Address, Telephone and Email). Unless the user changes one of these properties, I do not want the Update button enabled.

Thanks!

Command code (I am unsure as to what kind of validation to put in the CanExecute)

```
    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    private void CreateUpdateCommand()
    {
        UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateExecute, CanExecuteUpdateCommand);
    }

    private void UpdateExecute(object obj)
    {
        ClientModel.UpdateClient(_selectedClient);
    }

    private bool CanExecuteUpdateCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can have a bool flag like **hasChanges** which is false initially.and in the **setter** of your modifiable properties you set it true and after updating set it false again.and in CanExecute return this hasChanges instead of true. Suppose you have property Name

```
private bool hasChanges=false;
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            hasChanges = true;
            Notify("Name");
        }
    }

    private bool CanExecuteUpdateCommand(object obj)
    {
        return hasChanges;
    }
 private void UpdateExecute(object obj)
{
    ClientModel.UpdateClient(_selectedClient);
    hasChanges=false;
}
```

I hope you got an idea.